# Can't get Customer Account Data API working in PHP

Tags: php, intuit-partner-platform

I'm trying to get Intuit CAD API to work from within a PHP application. I've read the docs using the [recommended "SDK"](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/devkits#/php) (well, more like a demo app), search the web and tried multiple advice scattered here and there. Here's what I came up with:

```
        // I also use log file for curl - which doesn't add any info
        $curl_logfile = fopen('/tmp/curl_debug', 'w+');
        $ch = curl_init();
        $options = array();
        $options[CURLOPT_VERBOSE] = true;
        $options[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = true;
        $options[CURLOPT_TIMEOUT] = 360;
        $options[CURLOPT_CERTINFO] = false;
        $options[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
        $options[CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT] = true;
        $options[CURLOPT_STDERR] = $curl_logfile;
        $options[CURLOPT_URL] = $signed_request['signed_url'];
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
        $raw = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($error_num = curl_errno($ch)) {
            $error_desc = curl_error($ch);
        }
        // debug - get all info about the request just issues
        $all_data = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

The code above return 400 as the return code (viewable using curl_getinfo()) and empty string in $raw.

**How can I make my PHP app talk to Intuit CAD API?**

Also, on the same note - some API method require transferring parameters, so it seem, as part of the path. For example: [getInstitutionDetails](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/0020_api_documentation/0011_institutiondetails) (v1/institutions/**INST-ID**). Can I put those variables as parameters? Otherwise, I need to craft each request non-generically, according to the specific API method used :-(

Thanks!